# Exception claiming messages from Cloud Queues in fog

Tags: fog, rackspace

I've been running a process that consumes messages off of a Rackspace Cloud Queue for some time now. A while ago, I started seeing this exception in my logs at the line where I was creating a claim:

```
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
/home/ash/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.19.0/lib/fog/rackspace/models/queues/claim.rb:112:in `create'
/home/ash/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.19.0/lib/fog/rackspace/models/queues/claim.rb:46:in `save'
/home/ash/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.19.0/lib/fog/rackspace/models/queues/claims.rb:36:in `create'
```

What's changed? Is this a fog problem, or is there something wrong with Cloud Queues?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that, after a server upgrade, Cloud Queues started to use lowercase HTTP headers in some of its responses. Specifically, `Location` is now `location` and `Content-Type` changed to `content-type`. HTTP specifies that HTTP headers are case-insensitive, but as of 1.19.0, Fog's header access is not.

This is now fixed in `master`, so you can depend on the latest code by adding this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'fog', github: 'fog/fog'
```

Comment: Thanks for helping us out with that and updating this. Hoping to cut a release with the fix sometime in the earlier portions of this week, but not certain of timing yet.

Comment: I would hope the fix is upstream (i.e. CloudQueues) not the downstream libraries.